# Translate everything except posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to translate everything (menu, strings, static pages) but not user posts. Without having to insert the post twice in the database.

I mean if a user searches the category `casa` he should be able to see every English post in the category `home`.

Polylang or not, whatever. Without the use of a child theme, I'm using a custom theme that gets messed up whenever I use a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPML plugin for translation in different languages and in backend they are giving options whether to translate posts or not in any specific language which you have chose